# conditions on a morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ to ensure $X$ is reduced, given $Y$ is reduced?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $X,Y$ be finite type projective schemes over $\mathbb{C}$, and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a surjective morphism (but not an isomorphism). Suppose it is known that $Y$ is reduced, and the fibers of $f$ are reduced as well.

Are there any known results about $f$, which ensures that $X$ is also reduced?

There are similar results for connectedness, but I can't find anything for reducedness.

Comment: With these assumptions, the answer is no: take $X=Y\amalg Z$ where $Z$ is an non-reduced closed subscheme of $Y$.

Answer (score 3):

In Lemma 1.4. of [this](https://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_abstract.php?issn=0034-5318&vol=14&iss=1&rank=1) article, it is proven that $f$ flat, $X$ pure dimensional and $Y$ irreducible ensures that $X$ is reduced in your case.

Maybe some of these requirments can be relaxed, I haven't thought really thought about it.